# How to mix ingredients in bread machine?

Tags: bread, mixing

Following the catalog instruction I simply put ingredients into bread machine. However, when I got the dough, it contained particles of yeast.

Then, I decided to dissolve the yeast into water (as an ingredient) before adding to the mixture in bread machine. In this method, I found that the dough rises less.

What is the best way to mix ingredients for bread machine recipe? Is it helpful or harmful if briefly mixing the ingredient to be sure about dough consistency or it is better to leave everything for the bread machine?

Comment: You should always read and follow the directions of your particular bread machine, and use recipes designed for bread machines.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ If I understand right, "catalog instruction" means the bread machine's manual. Is that right, All?

Comment: Most bread machines specify a layering of the ingredients so that they mix thoroughly....  that is more specific than simple putting in the ingredients.

Comment: @Jefromi yes it is manual, but it simply instructs to add ingredients to the machine, no instruction about layering or something like that. The manual mainly contains recipes (ingredients and their amounts), and the machine specifications and description.

Comment: Some (many) bread machines don't mix well, so you might not get a good mixture whatever you do. But it's worth trying. If you are making the bread immediately after adding the ingredients, it probably doesn't matter much how you add the ingredients; just put the yeast and the sugar and such in the centre. If you use the timer, it is important that the yeast stay dry up until the moment the machine starts mixing. What gave me the best result is this: add water, sugar, salt, egg, fat; mix this by moving the pan around until the ingredients are mostly dissolved (or stir with a wooden implement);

Comment: ...then put all the flour in a heap in the centre of the pan; make a hollow in the centre of this heap, put the yeast in this hollow. Then set the timer. Another tip: if you put the pan on a kitchen scale while adding ingredients, and you press "tare" on the scale after each ingredient, it's much easier to weigh everything. (Only applies if you use ingredients by weight, of course.) Lastly, experimenting with amounts that differ from the recipe may greatly improve your bread. It depends on the machine. I also found that the "French" setting on the machine (longer baking) gave the best crust.

Comment: @Cerberus I believe your comments can make a useful answer.

Comment: @All: Done! <filler text>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some (many) bread machines don't mix well, so you might not get a good mixture whatever you do. But it's worth trying.

If you are making the bread immediately after adding the ingredients, it probably doesn't matter much how you add the ingredients; just put the yeast and the sugar and such in the centre.

If you use the timer, it is important that the yeast stay dry up until the moment the machine starts mixing. What gave me the best result is this:

1. add water, sugar, salt, egg, fat;
2. mix this by moving the pan around until the ingredients are mostly dissolved (or stir with a wooden implement);
3. then put all the flour in a heap in the middle of the pan;
4. make a hollow in the centre of this heap, put the yeast in this hollow;
5. then set the timer.

Another tip: if you put the pan on a kitchen scale while adding ingredients, and you press "tare" on the scale after each ingredient, it's much easier to weigh everything. This only applies if you use ingredients by weight, of course.

Lastly, experimenting with amounts that differ from the recipe may greatly improve your bread. It depends on the machine. I also found that the "French" setting on the machine (= longer baking) gave the best crust.

Answer (score 2):

the bread machine doesn't mix for very long.  For the yeast, however, use bread machine yeast which has much finer granules and dissolve faster in the water.

If you are planning to set the timer on the bread machine, keep the yeast away from the water as cerberus explains.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, make sure you're using yeast that has not passed the expiration date.  If you're finding chunks of yeast, you may want to check the dough during the knead cycle and hand knead a bit to make sure it is well combined.

How to add your yeast depends on two things, 1) what type of yeast (instant or active dry) and 2) when you plan to start your kneading cycle.

If you're kneading straight away and using Instant yeast, it doesn't matter what order you put the yeast in. Instant yeast has smaller particles, so it may mix in more easily as well.  If you're using active dry yeast, it may be better to add the yeast and sugar to the water first to dissolve and activate before you add all of your other ingredients.  The water should be at about 110 degrees F and the yeast-water mixture allowed to proof for about 10 minutes.  If it gets all bubbly and foamy, you know your yeast is good and it's ready to go.

If you plan to use a delay timer, add liquids first, then flour, then yeast on top to keep it dry.

If you're still not getting good results, you may want to increase the amount of yeast or decrease the amount of salt.  Salt (or too much sugar, like in sweet rolls) will inhibit yeast growth.  The general rule is 1/2 tsp salt per cup of flour.  You can also add 1Tbs of an acid like vinegar or lemon juice to give the yeast a jumpstart. Hope these tips help you out!